# Deploy create-react-app on Apache web server

Tags: reactjs

I using Apache HTTP Server build php mvc framework. 
**Domain: demo.com**

I want using react in sub web.

**Ex: demo.com/reactjs**

Now. I create new folder "`reactjs`"

**Step 1:** Create a `.htaccess` file in the reactjs folder  with content

```
RewriteBase /reactjs
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

**Step 2:** I'm get copied to the "build" folder when i run "npm run build"

But browser blank page. Please suggest a solution. Thanks.

Document for create-react-app : https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#user-content-serving-apps-with-client-side-routing

/*Update link*/

**Solution**: https://medium.com/@svinkle/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory-f694d46427c1

Comment: The question mentions Apache, but the link you posted to is talking about NodeJS (which has it's own web server)?

Comment: Thank! i fixed link

Answer (score 0):

Most likely those configs are been ignored by apache http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

To fix this, with `sudo` access you need modify the following file sometime has different name maybe `default.conf` or `000-default.conf`

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Note: `"/var/www/html"` is normally where you copy all the files to be served. Make sure to change it depending on your configurations setup